# Visual Studio 2012 XAML Designer hangs often

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a serious problem with Visual Studio 2012 XAML Designer that hangs often in these situations:

- Editing in designer and then edit a value in text editor or vice versa (often)
- Copy/paste operations (in text editor, specially with `ResourceDictionary` items) (very often)
- Change to another XAML document (unusual)

The only solution I have is killing `xdesproc.exe` process in Task Manager (if I don't do this, it would take over 15 minutes to be working again), but if I have a lot of XAML files opened I need to reload the designer wasting some time because the text editor hangs too when is loading.

Is very annoying, and I didn't have this problem with Visual Studio 2010.

What could be a viable solution for this issue?

Comment: open with the xaml file in "Source Code(Text) editor"?

Comment: The XAML designer is a tragedy.  It got very unstable at VS2012, do make sure that you have all the updates installed.  Current one is Update 4.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb7d638b-64ea-4e5a-b926-081b6abf1e58/xaml-editor-in-vs-2012-is-really-slow-and-locks-up-a-lot -googled a bit and found this

Comment: For me, the XAML designer is very important, if my computer was the problem the only solution would be setting only the source code editor, but everything worked fine when I had VS 2010, Microsoft as ever going backward with their software, trying to improve something and messing other things.